# Seidel Triangle

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

The Seidel Triangle is a mathematical construction similar to Pascal's Triangle, and is known for it's connection to the Bernoulli numbers.

The first few rows are:

```
      1
      1  1
   2  2  1
   2  4  5  5
16 16 14 10 5
16 32 46 56 61 61
```

Each row is generated as follows:

If the row number is even (1-indexed):

- Bring down the first item of the previous row
- Every next item is the sum of the previous item and the item above it
- Duplicate the last item

If the row number is odd:

- Bring down the last item of the previous row
- Going *backwards*, each item is the sum of the previous item and the item above it
- Duplicate what is now the first item.

Basically, we construct the triangle in a zig-zag pattern:

```
    1
    v
    1 > 1
        v
2 < 2 < 1
v
2 > 4 > 5 > 5
```

For more information, see [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#An_algorithmic_view:_the_Seidel_triangle) on Bernoulli numbers.

#### The Challenge:

Given `n`, either as a function argument or from STDIN, print or return either the `n`th row of the Seidel triangle or the first `n` rows. You may use either 0 or 1 indexing.

You do not need to handle negative or non-integer input (nor 0, if 1-indexed). You do not have to handle outputs larger than `2147483647 = 2^31 - 1`

As this is code-golf, do this in as few bytes as possible.

#### Examples:

In these examples the return value is the `n`th row, 0-indexed.

```
Input   ->  Output

0           1
1           1 1
2           2 2 1
6           272 272 256 224 178 122 61
13          22368256 44736512 66750976 88057856 108311296 127181312 144361456 159575936 172585936 183194912 191252686 196658216 199360981 199360981
```

Comment: "You do not have to handle outputs larger than your language's default int type" makes this trivial for languages with only 1-bit ints

Comment: Can the rows be outputted always sorted from small to large?

Comment: @ASCII-only Changed to match C++'s maximum int

Comment: @Angs No, the rows should be ordered as shown

Comment: @ASCII-only That's a default loophole (although IMO it's a bit poorly worded as it depends on what people would consider "reasonable")

Comment: @user202729 it's not a loophole if it's explicitly stated

Comment: @ASCII-only ... fine. OP can explicitly override loopholes. | Although this version is definitely better.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 66 bytes

```
<>(())<>{({}[()]<(()[{}]<<>{(({}<>{}))<>}>)>)}{}{{}<>{({}<>)<>}}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/38ZOQ0NT08auWqO6NlpDM9YGyI2uro21AQkBxYBULUi@1k7TTrO2urYaLASWAIkCqf//DY0B)

Row is 0-indexed.

```
# Push 1 (the contents of row 0) on other stack; use implicit zero as parity of current row
<>(())<>

# Do a number of times equal to input:
{({}[()]<

  # Subtract the row parity from 1
  (()[{}]<

    # For each entry in old row:
    <>{

      # Add to previous entry in new row and push twice
      (({}<>{}))<>

    }

  >)

>)}{}

# If row parity is odd:
{{}

  # Reverse stack for output
  <>{({}<>)<>}

# Switch stacks for output
}<>
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 67 bytes

This code abuses the `sort()` method and doesn't work on all engines.

Rows are 0-indexed.

```javascript
f=(n,a=[1],r)=>n--?f(n,[...a.map(n=>k+=n,k=0),k].sort(_=>n|r),!r):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYxBCoMwEADvvmJ7MosxKL3Vrn2ISAlWi0Z3JZFCafv2NLdhGGaxLxsGP@9HGfb5MfpN2I3vGCdSrC11da89UstleZuS6Ywx1mx2V0ytK4i1owq1600Qf6h7Kr8e9cnjxcZJvGIgqBpguBLU5wRFgfDJAAbhIOtoVnmmL6Q5mkVmVrnOEZvsF/8)

#### How?

We conditionally reverse an array by using the `sort()` method with a callback function that ignores its parameters and returns either **0** or a positive integer. *Don't try this at home!* This only works reliably on SpiderMonkey.

```
let A = [1,2,3,4,5] and B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

             | SpiderMonkey (Firefox)  | V8 (Chrome)             | Chakra (Edge)
-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------
A.sort(_=>0) | 1,2,3,4,5               | 1,2,3,4,5               | 1,2,3,4,5
A.sort(_=>1) | 5,4,3,2,1               | 5,4,3,2,1               | 1,2,3,4,5
B.sort(_=>0) | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 | 6,1,3,4,5,2,7,8,9,10,11 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
B.sort(_=>1) | 11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 | 6,11,1,10,9,8,7,2,5,4,3 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Note that V8 is probably using different sort algorithms depending on the length of the array (less or more than 10 elements).

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                     // f = recursive function taking:
  n,                      //   n   = row counter
  a = [1],                //   a[] = current row, initialized to [1]
  r                       //   r   = 'reverse' flag, initially undefined
) =>                      //
  n-- ?                   // decrement n; if it was not equal to zero:
    f(                    //   do a recursive call with:
      n,                  //     - the updated value of n
      [ ...a.map(n =>     //     - a new array:
          k += n, k = 0   //       - made of the cumulative sum of a[]
        ), k              //         with the last value appended twice
      ].sort(_ => n | r), //       - reversed if n is not equal to 0 or r is set
      !r                  //     - the updated flag r
    )                     //   end of recursive call
  :                       // else:
    a                     //   stop recursion and return a[]
```

Comment: What spider-monkey specific feature does this use?

Comment: @Downgoat It's taking advantage of the specific implementation of `sort()` in this engine. I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 52 bytes

```perl6
{(1,{[[\+] |.reverse,0]}...*)[$_].sort((-1)**$_*-*)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr@xBQjdbEqJL9BIz6aCnolgjEOvtNnMF3sd6ZGgizLVIo4u1S@vgJQ5P4BR07z4iQmWFd5ROvqXsjEIUHjtUX01bhiiFVxBPhtUMU/0B)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>89</s> <s>87</s> 82 bytes

```hs
(cycle[r,id]!!)<*>s
r=reverse
s 0=[1]
s n=let a=zipWith(+)(0:a)$(r.s$n-1)++[0]in a
```

Just `s` prints the lines in the zig-zag order, the anonymous function on the first row reverses half of the rows.

Thanks to @nimi for saving 5 bytes!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcUxDsIgFADQvaf4TTqAWAKrEW/g7IDE/ABaUkoIEBM9vNi3vAXr6mPsDhTcO7EfG70ux@DMONLz4VKHoop/@1L9UEEoLc1@UtE3QPUN@RbaQhgl4oR0IoXXKc2SMqaFCQmwb7inYMN8fQDJJaQGHBwFLTmX0vSffUZ81T7bnP8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
1;0SƤUƊ⁸¡U⁸¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Q2iD42JLQY12PGnccWhgKJv///28CAA)

Comment: You could remove the first `⁸`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>98</s> 91 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
f=lambda n:n and[*accumulate(f(n-1)[::n&1or-1]+[0])][::n&1or-1]or[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcyxCsIwEADQvV9xkyS1hQYHIeCXhAxnm2gguSvX6@DXR0fXN7z9o2@mW@9ZuEHRJMpcDyhtZ9FxyI@K7bkhkCdA2sKI63q2s6Imkw3Nzgbv6eJYZhevYYk2/gFLcLFnFiAoBIL0SmaZ7tYPALBLITU0wS@ytn8B)

Switching to 0-based row numbering saved 7 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>103</s> 97 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,r=[1],k=2:n and f(n-1,[sum(r[-2::-1][:i],r[-1])for i in range(k)],k+1)or r[::-(-1)**k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYsxDsMgDADn5hUecQqDUSckXoIYqFJai8aJnHTo6ylzxzvd7d/ztYnvvcZ3We9LAbEaE2Xbog8CRRaoRhzZdHxWo8n5EBzlFDjbQZSxbgoMLKBFng/TcLxXwmE1jdY4wnluuf91dMMwXXZlOYFtNYxT/wE)

Non-recursive version (easier to read):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 106 bytes

```python
def f(n,r=[1],j=1):
 while n:
	a=r[-2::-1];r=r[-1:];n-=1;j=-j
	for x in a+[0]:r+=[r[-1]+x]
 return r[::-j]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc1BCsMgEIXhtZ5ilgYVaujK4ElkFkK1UcokDAlNT2/j7i2@x7//jnWjufdXLlAUGQ7RoWnBTV7Cd62fDOSlSIGjnb23Dhce23lcyAa3tGCbFGVjuKASJB0f6FmHOBDqCyVwPk4m4Hj/G/Zh67Cc6J2Ve94psXOlA6opqk6y/wE)

Surely, better is possible!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 91 bytes

```python
from numpy import *
s=lambda n:n and cumsum(s(n-1)[::n%2*2-1]+[0]).tolist()[::n%2*2-1]or[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcyxDsIgFAXQvV/xFhOo1kh1IvFLCANaqyTlPvKAoV@Pjs4nOXmvH8a191U4EVrKO8WUWSqNQ7lvIT2WQLCggIWeLZWWVFGYjHbW4jCP82T80V28PlfeYqnqH1ic8X1lIVAEScD7pcxN24EoS0RVOP02rfsX)

Comment: You can remove the space between `import` and `*`

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 85 bytes

```julia
r(l,n=cumsum(l))=[n...,n[end]]
w=reverse
f(n)=n<2?[1]:n%2<1?r(f(n-1)):w(r(w(f(n-1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3RasQgEEXf9yvyUlCwITM6oy4r@yEhD6VNYUtWFrdpPj/VNGmbhUGu557Rj3G4vPA8JzGoGF7H6328ikHK0Ma6rlVs@/jWdYcppP6rT/f@8C6iDPGE5xa6Y3zCE5yTyPAZpDxOIolpu0k539Ilfg4xE5BVCFXekYc/iCtUe6x/MCp8KMxWGEWKdhWtT7EqYxQ0DwL/CjrvsyJWDHl2Emw/oGaHWamMsZoJUFXMlhpvM3OuIetKC43TAOhLRAsOdDHBGM1gFoE8WfK6RIvk1pi3vPGLm09CdoV6ZnIIS8xe4x38i52cvwE)

This is a recursive solution in Julia. Note that it has 1-based indexing. Hence the tests.

Ungolfed version, to understand the logic:

```julia
function new_row(last_row)
    new_row = cumsum(last_row)
    push!(new_row, new_row[end])
    return new_row
end


function triangle(n)
    if n == 1
        return [1]
    elseif mod(n,2) == 0
        return new_row(triangle(n-1))
    else
        return reverse(new_row(reverse(triangle(n-1))))
    end
end
```

Asa bonus, here's a non-recursive version, but this is longer:

```julia
w=reverse;c=cumsum
r(l,i)=i%2<1?c([l...,0]):w(c(w([0,l...])))
f(n,l=[1])=(for i=2:n l=r(l,i)end;l)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

```
!z*:1İ_¡ȯ↔S:→∫;1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9odXNr//8heio6McSwX8KhyK/ihpRTOuKGkuKIqzsx////MTM)

There may be a better way for arriving at the rows in the correct order. To get the correct output, this program reverses every other row.

### Explanation

```
!z*:1İ_¡ȯ↔S:→∫;1
              ;1 array [1]
       ¡ȯ        apply the following functions repeatedly on it, collecting results:
             ∫   cumulative sum
          S:→    repeat the last element
         ↔       reverse it
                 this generates all the required rows
 z*              zip multiply that with:
   :1İ_          [1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,...]
                 which reverses every other row
!                Get row at input index
```

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

```
?I↔%2¹!¡ȯ↔S:→∫;1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/397zUdsUVaNDOxUPLTyxHsgOtnrUNulRx2prw////xsaAwA)

Uses a ternary instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>22</s></sup> 18 bytes

```apl
{⊖⍣⍵{⌽+\⍵,0}⍣⍵,1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR17RHvYsf9W6tftSzVzsGyNAxqIWI6BjWKvxPe9Q24VFv36Ou5ke9ax71bjm03vhR28RHfVODg5yBZIiHZ/D/NAVTAA)

Same method as my Husk answer.

-4 bytes from coltim.

### Explanation

```apl
{⊖⍣⍵{⌽(⊢,⊢/)+\⍵}⍣⍵,1} ⍵ ← input(n)
                  ,1  convert 1 to an array [1]
    {          }⍣⍵    apply the following n times:
            +\⍵       cumulative sum
      (⊢,⊢/)          duplicate the last element
     ⌽                reverse
 ⊖⍣⍵                  then reverse n times
```

Comment: Instead of duplicating the last element (`(⊢,⊢/)+\⍵`) could you instead do `+\⍵,0` to save 4 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 59 bytes

```hs
(k!!)<*>(iterate(r.scanr1(+).(0:))[1]!!)
r=reverse
k=r:id:k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBDsIgEADAO6/Y3haNpL14IOIPfEFtzIYuSmiRLMTni855XlQTb1sP7t4xDYO@HK4YGws1RjHVU5YJj9rgaLWep@VflDjhD0tllZzYuNrUd4oZHKxvBbBTuT0Ai8TcTNAwj8acl/71YaNn7Sdfyg8)

Answer (score 1):

## [k4](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/), 17 bytes

```
{x|:/x{|+\x,0}/1}
```

Adapted from @razetime's APL answer.